# Remove objects from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, xpath

I have an array that is populated using some xpath; so the items in the array could be as little as 1-20+.

I am populating it like so:

```
    var masterPath = $('items item', response.responseXML)
    masterPath.each(function (index, obj) {
    var assignments = $('> data > title', obj).text();
    courseHwork.push(assignments);
```

However, the xml is a bit different for each, ie

```
<data>
  <title>example</title>
</data>

<data>
  <title>example2</title>
  <duedate>03-21-12</duedate>
</data>

<data>
  <title>example3</title>
  <duedate>05-02-12</duedate>
  <availdate>04-01-12</availdate>
<data>
```

What I need is to only grab the latter two items (the 'data' that contains both a 'duedate' AND an 'availdate'.)

What would be the best way to go through all  tags that may exist in the xml, and then only grab the ones with duedates and availdates and put them into the array?

Comment: #1, that's not a standard array, it's a `jQuery.init` instance. #2 that's not xpath, it's jquery selector syntax.

Comment: FYI, there's a future deprecation planned for `$('> data > title', obj)` style DOM selection, where the first `>` selector has no left hand operand. You're best off avoiding that type of selector

Comment: @amnotiam, that's good to know, have a reference for that information?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yes, see the note in the docs for the [child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a different selector: http://jsfiddle.net/mKUxw/. This one selects only `<data>` items which have both a `<duedate>` and `<availdate>`:

```
$("> data:has(duedate):has(availdate) > title", obj)
```